# cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'commentaires'

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I would like to validate my XML code with an XSD. First, I created it without any namespace, and it worked correctly. However, I'd like to have a namespace but things get tricky here. Indeed, with the code provided below, when I try to validate my XML, whatever I put as elements will be considered "correct" by my software (Editix), even when it should be incorrect (eg. write a string instead of a date).

Could anyone help me please?

**Here is my XML code:**

```
<commentaires xsi:SchemaLocation="benoit@agroparistech.fr DM-commentaires.xsd"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:com="benoit@agroparistech.fr">

<com:commentaire id-commentaire="ID1">
    <com:date>
        2018-03-13
    </com:date>
    <com:auteur>
        Jean Dupont
    </com:auteur>
    <com:texte>
        La cuisine était délicieuce, je ne peux que vous conseiller l'entremet à la fraise!
    </com:texte>
</com:commentaire>
</commentaires>
```

**And here is the XSD code:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="benoit@agroparistech.fr" xmlns="benoit@agroparistech.fr" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:element name="auteur" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="date" type="xs:date"/>
<xs:element name="texte" type="xs:string"/>

<xs:attribute name="id-commentaire" type="xs:string"/>


<xs:element name="commentaire">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="date"/>
            <xs:element ref="auteur"/>
            <xs:element ref="texte"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute ref="id-commentaire" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="commentaires">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="commentaire" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Corrections:**

1. Change `xsi:SchemaLocation` to `xsi:schemaLocation`.  Case matters.
2. Place `commentaires` in the targeted namespace.
3. Place `id-commentaire` in the targeted namespace.
4. Change namespace value from an email address to a URI. (This is optional, but prefered.)

Corrected, valid XML and XSD follow:

### XML

```
<com:commentaires xsi:schemaLocation="http://agroparistech.fr/commentaires DM-commentaires.xsd"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xmlns:com="http://agroparistech.fr/commentaires">

  <com:commentaire com:id-commentaire="ID1">
    <com:date>
      2018-03-13
    </com:date>
    <com:auteur>
      Jean Dupont
    </com:auteur>
    <com:texte>
      La cuisine était délicieuce, je ne peux que vous conseiller l'entremet à la fraise!
    </com:texte>
  </com:commentaire>
</com:commentaires>
```

### XSD

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://agroparistech.fr/commentaires"
           xmlns="http://agroparistech.fr/commentaires"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <xs:element name="auteur" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="date" type="xs:date"/>
  <xs:element name="texte" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:attribute name="id-commentaire" type="xs:string"/>

  <xs:element name="commentaire">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="date"/>
        <xs:element ref="auteur"/>
        <xs:element ref="texte"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute ref="id-commentaire" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="commentaires">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="commentaire" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: @BenoitManoliu: You're welcome.  Please [**accept**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/234215) this answer if it's helped.  Thanks.